# Windows not detecting any audio device

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, power-supply

Yesterday there was heavy rain and lightning where I live.. due to that there was a short in power supply. I lost my 500gb harddisk and all the data in it.

Today I bought a new hard disk and installed Windows 7 64bit and all the driver. But my pc is not detecting any audio device. I tried pluging with both headphoes and speakers. also I tried re installing the audio drivers. I updated it to the latest version but still no luck.

[image]

I cannot make my speaker as a default device even though I have plugged in my speaker.

Could the short in the power supply cause the on board sound card to short out as well? or is there some settings I am missing out?

Comment: Go out and get yourself a good UPS (uninterrupted power supply) from your local electronics outlet.   I have had this happen to me as well and I lost my primary desktop, hard drive, everything to a power surge.  A UPS will provide surge protection and even allow your computer to run for 15 minutes or longer in the event of a power outage so you can shut down your computer gracefully.   Some units even have a USB cable that you attach from the UPS to your computer and if a power outage happens, the software will shut your computer down for you.

Comment: Here is the one I use.   I actually own 3 of these and they work great.  http://bit.ly/RlcSjQ

Comment: @Richie086 thanks I will buy one tomorrow. Do you think my other components are safe like motherboard, processor and graphic card. cause I have invested a lot of money in this pc.

Comment: It is usually immediately  evident if they are damaged in any way because your PC will not not work.   It seems like your sound card has been damaged, but luckily you could always buy a PCI or PCIE soundcard to replace your on board sound.   Have you noticed any other issues with your PC other than the audio not working?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1ojGg5d for a cheap PCIE soundcard

Comment: @Richie086 Every thing seem to be working fine fir now. I also checked temperature. Its around 30-35 which is very safe I think.

Comment: @Richie086 Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. I will go and get a sound card and ups tomo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrical damage can come in through the power outlet or network cables via your internet connection. An electrical surge will damage more than one item in most cases.

The chances are if the hard drive was damaged, other components were damaged as well. I would be suspect of every component in that computer as being damaged. An the items which work now, may end up bad in the near future. Electrical damage is weird that way.

Surge suppressors on all connections are vital, especially in these instances. I learned the hard way when I only had protection on the power side, but lightening came in through the telephone line and took out the motherboard and NIC.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Other components are working fine. Do you think my other components are safe like motherboard, processor and graphic card. cause I have invested a lot of money in this pc? Is there a way to check if a component is damaged by an  electrical surge?

Comment: Simply, No I do not. As I stated in my answer, there is no way to know what was damaged and the results may not show right away. You can take your chances and replace them as they fail. One thing you need to do first is buy a good surge suppressor which includes all connections.

Comment: I have one.. last time the same thing happened I had to only replace the fuse. But this time no luck. also does getting a UPS protect me from lightning and power surge?

Comment: Depends on the UPS. Most do, but they have protected and unprotected outlets on them. Look closely at what you buy. Remember, cheaper isn't always better when it comes to protecting your equipment.

Comment: One last question how can I differentiate a protected outlet for an unprotected one?

Comment: They are typically marked on the unit itself if they are different.